# i'm unable to get the Android Support library in Android SDK manager

Tags: android

This is the Screen shot of my Android SDK here i'm unable to get the android Support library package.please help me to get that package......https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIRIr.jpg

Comment: There's no screenshot.

Comment: Also, please explain in detail what "unable to get the android Support library package" means. What are your exact symptoms?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dFuZR.jpg  .....please open the link i'm using the eclipse Version: Neon Release (4.6.0) and unable to get the Android Support Library package in the extras of SDK Manager help me how to get that package.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. I've searched for awhile and no matter what solution I attempt the Android Support Library simply does not appear in the android SDK manager.